# Trouble getting VSFTPD server up and running

Tags: vsftpd

Installed vsftpd using a how-to step by step found online.  Installed without error.

1st error to pop: server didn't prompt for user/pass.  Found a doc, applied the fix, and can now use prompt to login.

However, sometimes the connection does not seem stable, directory listing hangs, other times doesn't.

Stumped.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1362398/edit) and add the exact steps you followed. It is not clear how you installed `vsftp`. The question cannot be answered as it is.